# How to add columns: edit, delete?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I want to use vue ag-grid. So I have looked in [Get Started with ag-Grid in Your Vue Project](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-getting-started/)
 article.

But I can't find any examples of how to add `delete` column as link-button?

```
<a :click="handleDelete">delete</a>

handleDelete(itemData) {
 // should open popup here base on itemData…
}
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
<template>
    <ag-grid-vue style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
                 class="ag-theme-balham"
                 :columnDefs="columnDefs"
                 :rowData="rowData">
    </ag-grid-vue>
</template>

    this.columnDefs = [
                {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
                {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
                {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
            ];

            this.rowData = [
                {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000},
                {make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000},
                {make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000}
            ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `cellRendererFramework` for custom column like this:

```
this.columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
  { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
  { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price' },
  { headerName: 'Delete', cellRendererFramework: 'DeleteCell' }
];
```

Also make sure you registered your `DeleteCell` component:

```
components: {
  AgGridVue,
  DeleteCell,
},
```

Comment: and how I get the current field from the DeleteCell component?